# Want to extract two-dimensional array from three-dimensional array

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm populating a multi-sheet excel spreadsheet from a Lotus Notes database using a LotusScript agent in Notes.
In order to optimise the code, I'm building all the data in an array first, then dumping it into Excel, as it's much quicker to write an array in one go, than write each cell or row individually.

So I have a three dimensional array holding the data defined by

```
ReDim sheetData(sheets,rows,columns)
```

I have no problem populating the array, using view navigator entries, but when I come to write to Excel, I wanted to do

```
For c = 0 to sheets
   With xlSheet(c+1)
      .Range(.Range.Cells(1,1) , .Range.Cells(rows+1, columns+1).Value = sheetData(c)
   End With
Next
```

That doesn't work, obviously, because I need to give three subscripts for sheetData.

So what's the best way to extract the rows and columns data?

Answer (score 2):

You have two possibilites: 
You could run through all rows and columns and assign the value directly:

```
With xlSheet(c+1)
    For row = 1 to rows + 1
        For col = 1 to columns + 1
           .cells( row, col ) = sheetData(c,row,col)
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Or -if you CAN assign a two dimensional array to a range (what I don't know) you could work with a List of two dimensional arrays:

ReDim sheetData( row, col ) List as Variant

That would look like
`sheetData( 1 ) = [1,2]`

and then the assignment would look like:

```
.Range(.Range.Cells(1,1) , .Range.Cells(rows+1, columns+1).Value = sheetData( c )
```

BUT: Filling that List of Arrays might be a pain (create a temporary two dimensional array with ReDim, fill that Array and assign it like `sheetData( sheet ) = tempArray

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Torsten.  I tried this way, but couldn't work out how to create a List of Arrays (and googling didn't provide any definitive answers).
However, I have now realised that this method isn't going to be very pretty as my sheets will not have the same number of rows in, and I would really rather not create Arrays that will have numerous blanks (.e.g one sheet will have 22000 rows, and another will have 1700).  So I'm using 6 writing the data a row at a time, rather than a sheet at a time.  Still faster than writing it a cell at a time though :-)

Comment: Your 3D array is wasting memory, extremely. Suggestion about list of arrays is excellent one. You can make it by Dim sheetList List As Variant. New sheet is made by sheetList("sheet name") = array... and referenced as sheetList("sheet name")(i, j)